# How to solve this problem related to normal distribution?

Tags: stochastic-processes, normal-distribution

Given two independent and identically distributed Gaussian random variables $X$ and $Y$. How to calculate the probability that these two random variables are not equal for a period of time $T$?

Here, at any time point $t$, the random variables $X$ and $Y$ are Gaussian distributed.

Is this related to stochastic process?

Comment: How are $X$ and $Y$ affected by time?

Comment: In my world, a random variable is a real-valued (generally) function on a probability space. If $X$ and $Y$ are random variables, therefore, they are either equal or not equal --- there's no notion of a period time $T$. It's like asking "for how long is $3$ not equal to $5$?" Perhaps you could explain how time enters into your particular formulation of this problem.

Comment: Here, at any time point t, the random variables X and Y are Gaussian distributed.

Comment: Is there any assumption of continuity here? Is the value of $X$ at time $t$ related in any way to the value of $X$ at time $s$ for $s \ne t$, aside from being drawn from the same distribution?

Comment: Actually, there are not such assumptions. But you can make any assumption that you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, I'm gonna make a stab at answering this not-so-clearly formulated question. I'll probably mess it up, and someone who knows more about probability than I do will mock me, but... instead of doing that, they can write their own answers.

I'm going to simplify by assuming the mean is $0$ and the variance is $1$, so that the pdf is 
$$
s(x) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\exp(-\frac{x}{2}).
$$

The domain for the random variable $X$ is
$$
\Bbb R \times [0, T]
$$
which is also the domain for $Y$. We therefore can consider
$$
U = \Bbb R \times \Bbb R \times [0, T]
$$
as a probability space, with probability measure 
$$r(x, y, t) = s(x) s(y) \frac{1}{T}.$$

We can also define
$$
h: U \to \Bbb R: (x, y, t) \mapsto \begin{cases} 1 & x = y \\ 0 & x \ne y \end{cases}.
$$
We'd like to find the probability of the event $E = \{ (x,y,t) \mid h(x, y, t) = 1 \}$. That's the probability that at any time between $0$ and $T$, the two random variables are equal.

That probability is, by definition, just 
\begin{align}
p 
&= \int_{0}^T \int_{-\infty}^\infty \int_{-\infty}^\infty h(x, y, t) r(x, y, t) dx ~ dy ~ dt \\
&= \int_{0}^T \int_{-\infty}^\infty \int_{-\infty}^\infty h(x, y, t) s(x) s(y) \frac{1}{T} dx ~ dy ~ dt \\
&= \int_{0}^T \frac{1}{T} \left(\int_{-\infty}^\infty \int_{-\infty}^\infty h(x, y, t) s(x) s(y)  dx ~ dy\right) ~ dt \\
&= \int_{0}^T \frac{1}{T}~dt  \left(\int_{-\infty}^\infty \int_{-\infty}^\infty h(x, y, 0) s(x) s(y)  dx ~ dy\right)  \\
&= \int_{-\infty}^\infty \int_{-\infty}^\infty h(x, y, 0) s(x) s(y)  dx ~ dy  \\
&= \int_{-\infty}^\infty \left(\int_{-\infty}^\infty h(x, y, 0) s(x)  dx\right) s(y) ~ dy  \\
\end{align}
where the substitution of $0$ for $t$ is valid because $h$ is independent of its third argument. Looking at that last integral, let's fix $y$ for the moment, and look at the inner integral. It is 
$$
I = \int_{-\infty}^\infty h(x, y, 0) s(x)  ~ dx.
$$
The integrand is $s(x)$ only at the single point where $x = y$; otherwise it's equal to $0$. If two functions agree at all but a single point, their integrals are equal, so  we have
\begin{align}
p 
&= \int_{0}^T \int_{-\infty}^\infty \int_{-\infty}^\infty h(x, y, t) r(x, y, t) dx ~ dy ~ dt \\
&= \int_{-\infty}^\infty \left(\int_{-\infty}^\infty h(x, y, 0) s(x)  dx\right) s(y) ~ dy  \\
&= \int_{-\infty}^\infty \left(\int_{-\infty}^\infty  0  dx\right) s(y) ~ dy  \\
&= \int_{-\infty}^\infty  0 ~ dy  \\
&= 0.
\end{align}

In short: the probability (with respect to the probability measure described above) that $X(t) = Y(t)$ at some time $t$ with $0 \le t \le T$ is zero. So the probability that they're different throughout the given time interval is one. (This doesn't mean that they'll always be different -- merely that this happening is a probability-one event.)

Comment: Thank you very much, and I have got your point that its probability is always 0.But I have came up with a new idea.

Comment: What if we let Z = X - Y, then Z is normal distributed. If we want to calculate the probability that Z equals zero, it follows a inverse Gaussian Distribution.

Comment: Do you think it could make sense?

Comment: Sure, $Z$ is normally distributed for each time. The probability that it's zero is still zero. In the computations I did above, this (roughly) amounts to substituting $u = x + y; v = x-y$ in the double-integral, but there's no change in the end result.